# using `extern` with typedef-name

Tags: c++11, templates, c++14, alias

if we have

```
typedef std::vector<int> INT_VEC
```

if I use `INT_VEC` in any source file like this -

```
extern template class INT_VEC
```

I get error -
**using typedef-name `INT_VEC` after `class`**

Even `using` (aka through `alias`) does not solve it. How can it be resolved.

Comment: I don't think any compiler except the EDG frontend supports extern templates.

Comment: I tried gcc and msvc both supported `extern` but not for typedefs.

Comment: Oh my bad, I'm thinking about `export template`. Never mind my comment.

Comment: @rubenvb so do you have any idea, how to `extern` `typedef`

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? I only know extern to declare a variable defined elsewhere, I've never seen it used for a type...

Comment: I want to declare my all `vector`, `map` into a separate header file and later use them into different source files. Now in all source files except one, I will use `extern`. So crust of the problem is I wanted to `extern` `alias` not original name.

Comment: If I understand you correctly, you just need "extern INT_VEC variable_name;" for each of the variables. Do note that these are global variables and should be avoided if possible.

Comment: You cannot tell the compiler "my type is defined somewhere else in this or another translation unit", as you might to for variables (static/global). Remember that `extern` in this context applies only to variables - it cannot be applied to types. Have you tried - `extern Int32..` where `Int32` is typedef to some int type?

Answer (score -1):

Something like this ?

extern INT_VEC your_external_variable;